# Maven - find which jar class is coming from

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar

I am building a jar with dependencies using maven, when I run that jar I get error `Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path`, I excluded all log4j-over-slf4j dependencies from pom.xml but still getting same error. I tried using dependencies tree `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -pl myModule -am > dependencytree.log` but still could not figure out where these dependencies are coming from. I see class `org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory` in stacktrace is throwing error, is there a way to figure out where this class is coming from(which jar)?

May be something like `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=<classnamehere> -pl myModule -am > logsOfBuild.log`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String path = org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

This will tell you the jar file that the class is in.

Comment: thanks a lot, this method helps me.  I meet a fat jar and can't find the class come from which dependency. mvn dependency:tree can't solve this problem.